# Laravel int a binário de 32 bits (e vice-versa)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, binary

Numa tentativa de criar uma coluna com números 32-bit binários

```
/**
 * Run the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('teams', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->char('binary_number', 32)->charset('binary'); // Em: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62615777/5675325
        $table->timestamps();

    });
}
```

Sendo de destacar

```
$table->char('binary_number', 32)->charset('binary');
```

Quando vejo a mesma através da HeidiSQL posso ver que é do tipo `BINARY` com tamanho 32.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ao criar o seeder para popular com os dados desejados, experimentei

```
/**
 * Run the database seeds.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function run()
{
   DB::table('teams')->insert([
    'id' => 1,
    'binary_number' => 2,
    'created_at' => now(),
    'updated_at' => now()
    ]);
```

Acontece que se eu uso 2 ou 101 no `binary_number`, vou ter como resultado na DB o valor 2 ou 101, respetivamente.

Quanto eu experimento `00000000000000000000000000000010` (que equivale ao 2 em 32-bit binário) e `00000000000000000000000001100101` (que equivale ao 101 em 32-bit binário)

```
'binary_number' => 00000000000000000000000000000010,
```

então depois obtenho os valor 8 e 294977, respetivamente.

Todavia, o que eu procuro é que o 2 seja guardado como `00000000000000000000000000000010` e o 101 como `00000000000000000000000001100101`.

Comment: 294977₁₀ (decimal) = 1100101₈ (octal) e 8₁₀ (decima) = 10₈ (octal)

Comment: @AugustoVasques e se eu quiser que 2 seja armazenado como `0000000000000000000000000000000000000010`?

Comment: Não é com o armazenamento que tem que se preocupar é com a formatação ao exibir os dados. Eu estou sem o link acho o servidor de documentação PHP está em manutenção mas tem as funções `decoct()` e `base_convert()` para o auxiliar.

Answer (score 1):

Segundo [apokryfos](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66814465/5675325)

> O que estás a ver é o número a ser codificado na base 8, isto porque estás a prefixá-lo com um 0 (seguido de mais 0s) o que faz 010 base 8 == 8 base 10.
>
> Em PHP para indicar que um número é de uso binário `0b10`, pelo que o teu código seria:
>
> `'binary_number' => 0b00000000000000000000000000000010, // this is2 in decimal`
>
> Se quiseres que o número decimal 10 seja armazenado na base de dados, basta utilizar:
>
> `'binary_number' => 10,`
>
> Note-se que parece que a tradução para binário está a acontecer no final da base de dados, pelo que não é necessário passar o número binário se não o desejares.
>
> Se quiseres forçar o número para uma cadeia binária do comprimento dado, podes usar
>
> `$binaryString = str_pad(base_convert(2, 10,  2),32,'0',STR_PAD_LEFT);  // '00000000000000000000000000000010'`
>
> Para mais detalhes -
> https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php